# retrieving index of type long from Arraylist<Long>

Tags: java, arraylist

In Java,I have an ArrayList,
`ArrayList<Long> arr = new ArrayList<Long>();`

How do I apply the `get(index)` method to the above list, when index is also of type `long`, i.e. the number of elements in the arraylist exceeds the type `int`, and therefore requires usage of the type `long`.

Comment: You can't. Arrays are limited to `int` indices by the language spec.

Comment: You can't, the only thing you can do is use `iterator()` (or obviously `for(Long li : arr) {}`) or if you need to iterate through it only once then even `get(0); remove(0);` would work.

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: Thank you. How else can I store and access a lot of numbers ( when the quantity exceeds the range of int )?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` internally stores data in `array` and array can have maximum index of Integer.MAX_VALUE so you can't go beyond that you can cast this value to `long` if you like to (which doesn't help)

Answer (score 0):

You can't define the type of `index` for `ArrayList` in Java. They are `int` by design.

You can define the type of the `ArrayList` wich values you are going to store there

```
List<Long> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1.01L);// adding long value
```

You can get the value

```
list.get(0)//  0th index
```

And limit of `index` is equals to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

You may not do that, Arrays can only use int values and is specified that way.

Here is a forum thread that discusses why:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/455957/java/java/array-index-integer

Hope this helps